# How to render an animation at a higher framerate?

Tags: rendering, animation

Is there an easy way to render an animation at a higher framerate?

I'd like the playback speed to remain the same, but to have more in-between frames.

---

As far as I can tell, the *framerate* dropdown in the render settings only changes the playback speed.

Comment: That is what the `Framerate` setting does, it tells Blender how many frames to play per second. The problem is that the keyframes and/or simulations need to be scaled as well. I ran into the same issue, and basically what people were saying is start at the right framerate, as there is no easy way to scale all simulations and animations :-( Hopefully I can be proven wrong on this one! Maybe a touch of Python?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I think except for fluid and smoke all the other simulations can be interpolated relatively easily (IIRC particles already support the time remapping setting). Keyframes also support time remapping

Comment: Awesome! So it shouldn't be too hard to implement some code to do it automatically?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I think it would really just be a matter of calculating the right values for time remapping

Comment: I hope someone with some coding experience in Blender can code a solution! That would be so handy to be able to do!

Comment: you can just use the same frame rate until rendering ( chnage just before render )?

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Change it via the dropdown in render settings? AFAICT that only changes the playback speed; The resulting animation has the same number of frames.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Blender has settings to help with this.

Let's start with 250 frames at 24fps

[image]

Let's say we want to get 4 times as many frames for the same time. Change the end frame to 1000, the frame rate to 96 (you could also leave the framerate and alter the framerate base to 0.25) and everything plays faster. Just under the framerate we have time remapping, change the new value to 400 as we have done 4x to everything else. Now when you render you will get 1000 frames and the animation will cover the same amount of movement.

[image]

**Warning-** You will notice that this feels "not fully supported" throughout blender, a keyframe in the timeline will remain at frame 250 while the timeline is highlighted to show the render ending at 1000, the current frame marker will only move to 250, as you try and position the current frame in the timeline, dopesheet or graph editor the frame marker will lag behind the cursor. It can be strange to have the frame move to nowhere near the cursor until you remember why. I recommend you alter these settings only during rendering.