# Why is my animation choppy when I render it?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

So I just made a very short animation. what will be my youtube intro, its 20 frames long and the animation is very choppy. How do I fix this?

Here is [the video file](https://www.mediafire.com/?2k1y6ac0jcs0qjn).

Comment: With just 20 frames, that is to be expected. That is less than one second of footage

Comment: What do you mean by "choppy"?

Comment: There are many things that could be happening, but it's very hard to guess without a blend file or a link to the animation in question.

Comment: It could be that you are expecting to much (animation or movement) to happen in a short time. If there are many keyframes for things like camera movement or rotation of objects, you could find that the interpolation or f-curves are very tight. This will look weird when you play it back.

Comment: added a link for a download to the .avi look at that then tell me what you think. I have a text object falling to the ground from frame 0 to frame 15

Comment: @cypherwave I think i'm having the same problem. Raw avi. file but I read this, threw it into movie maker, and it's still not working. I know this was a long time ago but do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can happen when fast moving objects result in a large difference between consecutive frames.

For reference, here's what my test scene looks like at 24 fps without any motion blur:

[image]

To fix this, you have a couple options:

### Increase the framerate

[Increase the framerate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/22870/599), adding more frames while keeping the same run time.

AFAIK youtube will play high framerate videos at a reduced framerate at lower user-set quality levels, so this may not be an ideal solution for youtube (the results may not be the same for all youtube quality settings).

Here's the same scene at 60fps (click the gif to see a better version):

[image]

### Add some motion blur

Add some motion blur to smooth the transition between frames

See [the manual](http://blender.org/manual/contents.html) for details on how to use motion blur [in blender internal](http://blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/motion_blur.html) and [in cycles](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/integrator.html#motion-blur).

[image]

### Or both

Of course, you can do both at once too ;)
<sub>Again, click the gif to see it in a video format..</sub>

[image]

---

Unfortunately gifs make terrible examples when showing framerate settings and SE doesn't support embedding of other formats. Click on any of the gifs to see it in a video format.

Comment: fantatic! I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: does computer lag affect the render at all? cause I'm getting 95 percent ram because i'm watching youtube while rendering...

Comment: @cypherwave Nope, as long as you have enough resources the render should be the same.

Comment: what do you mean by resources?And should I try to make the video longer?

Comment: @cypherwave Mainly memory. As long as it *can* render, the render will always be the same.  I'd probably make it a bit longer, but this is a more of an artistic choice.

Comment: ok see this animation was a work in progress. but i decided to test drive it and i ran into this slight problem. I will make it like 3 seconds long then try to render it again.

Comment: so that didn't work.. and the motion blur is doing absolutely nothing... is there a setting I might have changed to cause this? does disabling mipmap do anything special?

Comment: could you leave a link to the .blend file? I think I might be doing something wrong in relation to location of the objects... or I can leave a link to my blend file and you could let me know if anything is wrong...

Comment: @cypherwave I don't have that .blend anymore, but I'll be happy to take a look at your file :)

Comment: here you go! thank you for helping me! https://www.mediafire.com/?hq17bqy1a24nw4w

Comment: @cypherwave In the file you linked motion blur isn't enabled.. Note that for BI I'd probably use the *vector blur* node with the *vector pass* in the *compositor*. Here's a screenshot: http://pasteall.org/pic/85589

Comment: how would I link the file? and i figured out how to do the vector... I'm rendering the animation now.

Comment: so the 20 frames at 24 fps was greatly improved after I did the blur. I increased the fame rate to 60 and made the animation longer to see if that makes it beautiful. Thankyou so much for helping me!

Comment: so i figured out why my animation was so choppy, my media player was jumping around when playing the video. I think because it's a raw avi file. So  i threw it into movie maker and exported it there and now its perfect. *facepalm*