# Does changing the fps change the speed of the animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, video, audio

I had created animation in blender **2.76** with sound effects, at **30** fps, and rendered it at **60** fps. However, when I saw the rendered result, the video was **faster** than the sound. Does increasing the fps while rendering a video increase its speed? If yes, will simply rendering the animation at **30** fps solve the issue? If no, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render an animation at a higher framerate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/how-to-render-an-animation-at-a-higher-framerate)

Comment: Note that changing fps will affect physics. For example, if fps doubled, u may want to double gravity.

Comment: And gravity is just one of them, changing fps will change everything.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the keyframes (as the name indicates) of blender animations are based on frame numbers instead of absolute time. So if you render an animation that has been created with 30fps in mind at 60 fps, the video will be half the length.

If you really want it to be 60 fps and you do not want to redo the whole animation, you could make use of the "time remapping" parameter (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html), as described here for example: [How to render an animation at a higher framerate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/how-to-render-an-animation-at-a-higher-framerate)